# Caption bar not being repainted in MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc

Alright, I'm using `VS2012` with `MFC` in `Windows 8` and I'm having a problem.
Let's say I have a very simple dialog in my application. When I click on a different window (for example on the Taskbar), the caption bar color indicates that the dialog is still focused!

This problem happens in several cases. For example, when I use `CFileDialog` to select some files, after closing the dialog, caption bar color indicates that the dialog is still inactive while it's automatically focused after closing the open dialog!

Now let's say I have two dialogs in my application. Dialog A is my primary dialog and I use a button to show modal dialog B. In standard applications, if I click on dialog A, dialog B caption bar flashes. This doesn't happen in my application and I think it's because of a bug in `MFC`.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you handling WM_NCPAINT in any way?

Comment: Post repro code. I highly doubt it's a bug in MFC, but if you can reproduce it in a simple application like you describe, we can find out for sure and either come up with a workaround or file a bug report.

Comment: Something's borken in your message handling.  WM_ACTIVATE most likely.  Don't look for an mfc bug to explain this away.

Comment: Guys just create a new project. You'll face the problem!

Comment: :O I overrided `OnActivate` and commented the call to `CDialogEx::OnActivate`. Surprisingly, it fixed the problem! Any idea what is the reason?

Comment: It must be `CDialogEx` because when I call `CDialog::OnActivate` I see no problem.

Comment: Is [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672452) related? It was supposedly fixed but sounds very similar.

Comment: Yeah, it should be fixed in VS2012; but it isn't.